# redirecting pages does not redirect when on mobile

Tags: php, redirect, mobile, verification

Okay, so I have maconbeercompany.com which has an age verification redirect on it. It works great in IE, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. Only problem is that I cannot get it to work with mobile devices. When on an iphone or android, I cannot leave the age verification page unless I hit 'no'. I want users to be able to click 'yes' and visit the beer company's website. Below is the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
// This code, including the enclosing ?php tags, will require age verification for this page if included at the beginning of the associated HTML/PHP file.
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['age_verified']) || $_SESSION['age_verified'] != true)
{
    // Direct them to the age verification page
    $redirect_url = urlencode("http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );

    header('Location: http://maconbeercompany.com/age-verification.php?redirect=' . $redirect_url );
} 
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to store it in the session?? If you dont do anything more with the verification, only redirecting...why not use a link '<a>' ??

Comment: Has the mobile device your using to test this, got cookies enabled?

Comment: @Tiago he probably wants it to remember the users answer, so they don't have to keep verifying their age

Comment: @Fred-ii- He is using iframes to PHP files. when i first see it i thought it was only html, thats why i told him to do only with <a> but then i swa the iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes header doesn't work very well with sessions so i would recomend you try:

```
$redirect_url = urlencode("http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );

echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='0; url=http://maconbeercompany.com/age-verification.php?redirect=". $redirect_url."'>";
```

Comment: @Lissy is right. I need sessions because I need the verification to work for all pages of the site. Example, if Tom goes directly to the about us page, I don't want anyone to be able to bypass the age verification. But at the same time, I don't want each visitor to have to verify for each page they visit.

Comment: I am a novice to all of this coding, so I really appreciate all of your help! @Fred -ii- Where would I place that code? In the header?

Answer (score 0):

";
echo "window.open(``Location: http://maconbeercompany.com/age-verification.php?redirect=` . $redirect_url `, `_parent`, ``)";
echo " ";




} 
?>